# Create GMail Search/Filter for Subject with an Apostrophe

Tags: filter, gmail

I'm attempting to create a GMail search/filter that identifies messages with an apostrophe in the subject line (anywhere) but having difficulty (and thinking this should be simple).

I've tried:

- subject:'
- subject: "'"
- subject: \'
- subject: (')
- subject: (\')
- subject: ("\'")
- subject: '
- subject: '

Anyone have an idea how to do this?